# Instruction latency associated with vector intrinsic load from memory versus register in HPC application

Tags: assembly, cpu-architecture, simd, hpc

Is there any performance difference between the following assembly snippets utilizing vector instrinsics:

```
vmovapd ymm0, YMMWORD PTR [Address]
vaddpd  ymm0, ymm0, YMMWORD PTR [Address]
```

and

```
vmovapd ymm0, YMMWORD PTR [Address]
vmovapd ymm1, YMMWORD PTR [Address]
vaddpd  ymm0, ymm0, ymm1
```

According to Agner Fog's micro-architecture description of the Ryzen Zen 3 CPU, there are two load/store ports. In the former case, these two ports might be used to load ymm0 and ymm1 concurrently, while in the latter case, ymm0 is loaded first and ymm1 is loaded during execution of the add instruction.

Comment: No, there should be no difference in performance.  The two generate essentially the same microcode.  However, there may be edge cases (e.g. frontend bottlenecks, code size issues) in which the performance may differ.

Comment: Latency is identical since the same uops are in the scheduler and execution units.  The whole point of decoding CISC instructions to uops is to schedule different parts independently.  *Throughput* can differ, though, since `vaddpd` with a memory source operand fits through the front-end as a single uop, and only takes one slot in the ROB so out-of-order exec can see farther past it.  (Except on Intel CPUs with an indexed addressing mode, where it will un-laminate.  [Micro fusion and addressing modes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26046634)  AMD doesn't have this downside.)

Comment: Given that AMD [invented](https://patents.google.com/patent/US6442677B1) superforwarding for the Athlon processor, it stands to reason that they continued using it in all of their subsequent processors.